# javascript fetch automatically changes http with https

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am making a request with fetch at the client side with this code:

```
    var request = new Request(`http://ip:8080/click?url=${value}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }),
    });
    fetch(request)
```

but when the browser makes the request, it automatically changes the URL with https protocol:

> **https://ip:8080/click?url=${value}**

Note: the webpage has SSL encryption

> Subsequently, I get this error on the webpage console: **Failed to
> load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**

Comment: The server doesn't support https requests, when I'm testing the webpage on my local browser I don't have any problem, but when doing it on the webpage with SSL encryption then the error happens.

Comment: What ?! you write in the comment the server "dosn't support https" and in your post, "the webpage has ssl encryption" ?!

Comment: yes, the webpage hosting has SSL encryption. The server where the API resides doesn't support https requests

Comment: I think your problem is CORS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @Marc How can it be a CORS problem since the changes from http to https is done by the browser?

Comment: @KarolBorkowski This depends. When the request comes from the same domain/hosts then not. If the origin of the request is "localhost" or a webserver which is under controll of op, then is *possible* a cors problem. But since op dosnt answer, nor post the request/response header, we would never know. We dont even know if its a client or server problem. So its just guessing what could cause the problem...

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and the reason was the following line in the head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

It replaces every http requests with https.

Comment: Note that this can also come from the HTTP headers of the page's response.

Comment: This was the issue for me in my template. I think this is something folks should check when they see unpredictable behavior.