# https access restricted - weather api

Tags: http, https, request, get, fetch-api

I am getting an issue with the Weatherstack API, I have a free plan that allows me to do 1000 requests per month but I always get an error while trying to make a GET request via JavaScript in a web page.

Is someone able to understand why it is trying to make a HTTPS request instead of HTTP and what is causing this?

The response is:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": 105,
        "type": "https_access_restricted",
        "info": "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."
    }
}
```

And the line of code that makes this request is the following:

```
fetch('http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key='+key+'&query='+cityName)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014802/javascript-fetch-automatically-changes-http-with-https

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript fetch automatically changes http with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014802/javascript-fetch-automatically-changes-http-with-https)